# Best string hash function for this example

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, hash, hashtable

i have a key with type AcccAA where A-[A...Z] (capital letters), and c is [1..9]. i have 1500 segments.
Now my temp hash function

```
int HashFunc(string key){   
    int Adress = ((key[0] +  key[1] + key[2] + key[3] + key[4] + key[5]) - 339) * 14;
    return  Adress;
}
```

and Excel show a lot of collision in center (from 400 to 900)

Please tell me the hash function to be more evenly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common way to build a hash function in this case is to evaluate some polynomial with prime coefficients, like this one:

```
int address = key[0] + 
              31 * key[1] + 
              137 * key[2] + 
              1571 * key[3] + 
              11047 * key[4] + 
              77813 * key[5];
return address % kNumBuckets;
```

This gives a much larger dispersion over the key space. Right now, you get a lot of collisions because anagrams like `AB000A` and `BA000A` will collide, but with the above hash function the hash is much more sensitive to small changes in the input.

For a more complex but (probably) way better hash function, consider using a string hash function like [the shift-add-XOR hash](http://en.literateprograms.org/Hash_function_comparison_%28C,_sh%29#Shift-add-XOR), which also gets good dispersion but is less intuitive.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is awesome. How u get that numbers? 31 137 1517. what the algorithm to take them?

Comment: Simply large prime numbers. Small prime numbers are more likely to produce collisions.

Comment: @user2872568- Prime numbers are strongly preferred here; they have much nicer dispersion properties. I'd recommend avoiding nice round multiples of ten.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to construct a guaranteed collision-free number (which will not make your hash table collision free of course), as long as the possible keys fit in an integral type (e.g. `int`):

```
int number = (key[0] - 'A') + 26 * (
              (key[1] - '0') + 10 * (
               (key[2] - '0') + 10 * (
                (key[3] - '0') + 10 * (
                 (key[4] - 'A') + 26 * (
                  (key[5] - 'A')
             )))));
```

This works since `26 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 26 * 26 = 17576000` which fits into an `int` fine.

Finally simply hash this integer.